# angular.js ng-hide not working

Tags: angularjs, alert, ng-hide

I am having an issue with using ng-hide. With all of the code below, I am able to get everything working the way I want it to until I add the ng-hide attribute, at which point it refuses to show ANY of the images. If I leave it out, the images all show up like I expect, leaving me to believe my controller is working correctly and I have hooked into it correctly. What am I not understanding? Also, you will see I put an alert in the function to make sure it is being called, but I cannot for the life of me get an alert box to work using angular.

app.js

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module("mainApp", []);

    app.controller("StoriesListController", ["$http", StoriesListController]);

    function StoriesListController($http) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.title = "Tutorial List";
        vm.imageIndex = 0;

        activate();

        function activate() {
            vm.stories = [];
            $http.get("api/Story").then(function (response) {
                vm.stories = response.data;
            });
        }

        vm.setCurrentImage = function (index) {
            vm.imageIndex = index;
        };

        vm.isCurrentImage = function (index) {
            alert(index);
            return vm.imageIndex === index;
        };
    }
}());
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="mainApp">
<head>
    <title>TEST</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/App.js"></script>
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>TEST</h1>
    <div ng-controller="StoriesListController as vm">
        <h1>{{vm.title}}</h1>
        <div class="container slider">
            <div ng-repeat="story in vm.stories">
                <img ng-src="{{story.PreviewImageURL}}" ng-hide="!isCurrentImage($index)" class="slide" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

StoryController.cs (the API I am calling to fill stories)

```
namespace AngularWebApi.Controllers
{
public class StoryController : ApiController
{
    private static readonly List<Story> apps = new List<Story>
    {
        new Story
        {
            ID = 1,
            Name = "Test 1",
            Descript = "Test 1 Desc",
            PreviewImageURL = "/Images/Test1.png",
            Views = 1,
            Ranking = 1
        },

        new Story
        {
            ID = 2,
            Name = "Test 2",
            Descript = "Test 2 Desc",
            PreviewImageURL = "/Images/Test2.png",
            Views = 1,
            Ranking = 2
        },

        new Story
        {
            ID = 3,
            Name = "Test 3",
            Descript = "Test 3 Desc",
            PreviewImageURL = "/Images/Test3.png",
            Views = 1,
            Ranking = 3
        },
    };

    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(apps);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Since you're not getting your alert, it means that your app never arrives at the alert(). If it would, there is nothing that could stop it, unless it's an error which you can check for in the console.

Comment: @Amar I just double checked and my console is clean. You do not happen to notice anything between the html and is that would be messed up would you? Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Seems like you didn't call the setCurrentImage function.

Comment: @andyhu I set it to 0 when initialize the controller, so I would think the fort image would show by default. When I did not get this behavior, I never went any further with adding anything to the html that would set the current image. Am I misusing $index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just miss `vm`. Try `ng-hide="!vm.isCurrentImage($index)"`.

Comment: Doh!! That was the issue... Sometimes I amaze myself (and not in a good way). Thank you very much for catching that one. I have upvoted, but I am too low for it to show yet. (Of course, the alerts are working now to haha!)

Comment: No problems. This kind of error happens to everyone.